How to Resolve IAM Recommender Alert for Service Agent with Excessive Permissions?
I am encountering a vulnerability reported by Google Cloud Security Command Center. The report states:
"IAM recommender detected that a service agent was granted one of the basic IAM roles: Owner, Editor, or Viewer. Basic roles are excessively permissive legacy roles and should not be granted to service agents."
The specific service account in question is of the format:
[PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
It appears to be the Google APIs Service Agent for my project, which was automatically created by Google Cloud. I have not manually assigned this service account or configured its roles.
My Questions:
Is it safe to modify the permissions of this service account, given that it was automatically created and assigned by Google Cloud?
What would be the correct way to fix this security issue without breaking Google Cloud services that depend on this account?
I want to address this vulnerability but am unsure of the consequences of removing the Editor role from the service account.
Thank you for your help!


If the detailed response I have drafted  helped you in clarifying the issue, I request you to give feedback as stated in the document. What should I do when someone answers my question?

Yes, it is safe to modify the permissions of this service account.
While disabling  the automatic role grant, you must decide which roles to grant to the default service accounts, and then grant these roles yourself. If the default service account already has the Editor role, you can replace the Editor role with less permissive roles.
To safely modify the service account's roles, use Policy Simulator to see the impact of the change, and then grant and revoke the appropriate roles.
You can also create custom roles and include only the recommended permissions which you can modify by adding or removing permissions.
As mentioned in the document:

On creation, some service agents are automatically granted a service agent role to ensure that your Google Cloud services work properly. If you replace this role with a basic role (Owner, Editor, or Viewer), a role recommendation might suggest that you restore the original service agent role to remove excess permissions, even if the service agent role has permissions that are not in the basic role. These recommendations have the subtype
SERVICE_AGENT_WITH_DEFAULT_ROLE. They help you safely remove excess permissions while ensuring that all Google Cloud services work properly.
SERVICE_AGENT_WITH_DEFAULT_ROLE recommendations are the only type of recommendation that might suggest roles with permissions not in the current role.

You can also learn more about how to revoke or replace an existing role.
